Elegant way to handle common parameters across multiple functions in TypeScript
I am working on a game and I want to have equivalent implementations of functions using different engines. I want to make sure they all get the same default parameters. Here are the ways I came up with and what I dislike about them:
The Sledgehammer Approach
function frobnicateA(req: number, opt: number = 5) {
    console.log(req, opt)
}

frobnicateA(1, 2)

function frobnicateB(req: number, opt: number = 5) {
    console.log(req, opt)
}

frobnicateB(1, 2)


parameters not named in calls
repetition of parameter names across implementations (without enforced consistency)
repetition of default arguments across implementations

The Common Way
(you get the point of frobnicateB, going to omit it henceforth)
interface Config {
    req: number
    opt?: number
}

function frobnicateA(cfg: Config) {
    let opt = cfg.opt ?? 5
    console.log(cfg.req, opt)
}

frobnicateA({ req: 1, opt: 2 })


lot of boilerplate when having many optional arguments
repetition of default arguments across implementations
can forget to fill parameters in implementations

The ES Way
interface Config {
    req: number
    opt?: number
}

function frobnicateA({ req, opt = 5 }: Config) {
    console.log(req, opt)
}

frobnicateA({ req: 1, opt: 2 })


repetition of default arguments across implementations
fails silently if default arguments are forgotten

The Almost There
interface Config {
    req: number
    opt?: number
}
const defaultOpt = 5

function frobnicateA({ req, opt = defaultOpt }: Config) {
    console.log(req, opt)
}

frobnicateA({ req: 1, opt: 2 })


fails silently if default arguments are forgotten
somehow rubs me the wrong way

The Extra Classy
class Config {
    req1!: number
    req2!: number
    opt: number = 5
    constructor(cfg: Pick<Config, 'req1' | 'req2'> & Partial<Config>) {
        Object.assign(this, cfg)
    }
}

function frobnicateA(cfg: Config) {
    console.log(cfg.req1, cfg.req2, cfg.opt)
}

frobnicateA(new Config({ req1: 1, req2: 2, opt: 3 }))


constructor awkward and confusing
unenforced repetition of required parameters in Pick
function calls more elaborate with new and Config

The Hack
type RequiredKeys<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Required<T>[K] ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

type FillsAndOverrides<T> = Pick<T, RequiredKeys<T>> & Partial<T>;

class Config{
    req!: number
    opt?: number = 5
    constructor(cfg: FillsAndOverrides<Config>){
        Object.assign(this, cfg)
    }
}

function frobnicateA(cfg: Config){
    console.log(cfg.req, cfg.opt)
}

frobnicateA(new Config({req:1, opt:2}))


function calls more elaborate with new and Config
abusing ? as a filter tag for RequiredKeys, which
fails silently if I call frobnicateA({ req: 1 })

The Filler Function
interface Config {
    req: number
    opt?: number
}

function fillConfig(cfg: Config): Required<Config> {
    return { ...{ opt: 5 }, ...cfg };
}

function frobnicateA(cfg: Config) {
    let fullCfg = fillConfig(cfg)
    console.log(fullCfg.req, fullCfg.opt)
}

frobnicateA({ req: 1, opt: 2 })


defaults somewhat hidden
no TS warning if I forget to call fillConfig in any implementation

The Callsite Filler Function
interface Config {
    req: number
    opt?: number
}

function fillConfig(cfg: Config): Required<Config> {
    return { ...{ opt: 5 }, ...cfg };
}

function frobnicateA(cfg: Required<Config>) {
    console.log(cfg.req, cfg.opt)
}

frobnicateA(fillConfig({ req: 1, opt: 2 }))


defaults somewhat hidden
feels like really the function should fill the config...

The Invalid Ideal
parameters Config {
    req: number
    opt: number = 5
}

function frobnicateA({req, opt}: Config) {
    console.log(req, opt)
}

frobnicateA({ req: 1, opt: 2 })

I understand that some of my dislikes are very nit-picky and in the end I can just use any of those ways. But it feels like there should be a nice solution that feels right and has none of these problems.

Maybe you should consider wrapping your functions with common parameters in a class, if the passed parameters are likely to stay the same.

@PRO in another context yes but I won't combine implementations of equivalent functions in different engines into a class (as in SceneMaker(config).makeThreeJsScene() and SceneMaker(config).makeBabylonScene()), instead all implementations that use the same engine will go into a class.

In my opinion, either Filler or Callsite Filler are the best options you'll be able to get between the type-safety, lack of repetition, and simplicity that you're seeking. Having the defaults be sort-of hidden may just be something to accept. You could extract the config to an object colocated with the interface definition if general visibility is the goal.
interface Config {
  req: number
  opt?: number
}

const configDefaults: Partial<Config> = {
  opt: 5 
}

function fillConfig(cfg: Config): Required<Config> {
  return { ...configDefaults, ...cfg };
}

function frobnicateA(cfg: Required<Config>) {
  console.log(cfg.req, cfg.opt)
}

frobnicateA(fillConfig({ req: 1, opt: 2 }))

You could also use a more specific approach in configDefaults with a Pick<...> instead of Partial, but that gets back into args repetition and cumbersome-when-large territory
const configDefaults: Pick<Config, 'opt'> = {
  opt: 5 
}


I was already wondering if there is a way to extract the optional fields in a type so we could do const configDefaults: Optionals<Config>

I found a way:
type Vacant = {
[K in keyof T as undefined extends T[K] ? K : never]-?: T[K];
};
(I was struggling to find a short descriptive name that suggests that optional fields are extracted and turned into required fields...)

Thats's a neat solution! It's a surprisingly difficult concept to name elegantly. Vacant is better than anything I've come up with so far. Optionals is also quite good, it leaves no qualms about what props you're getting back from T

To me, "Optionals" suggests that they are still optional... I think I'm going to do it like this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAIlAZgQwK4BsQGcA8AVAPhgF4YBvGAbQGkYBLAOxgGsowB7RGPGZLGVAwAmSRlCEwoADxBRh-PDQC6MAPwxaALhgMoANygAnJQFpV2xdSUBuGAF9rwYI1mGUAY1gBhdg0R0Ac3JgGFCYQygAR20GVABbACMjELD2CBBzHXikw2A7J3dfLBAYQr9AhBQMbG1KtExcH3KAolIyFNC0kG0AVjynREF3EDpfGERDdgSGOndkWQBBAAoy-wDtJrWASmCwmHQoEvdEILaYADpL1YqkeuwAGgur3zX7DtKi9gPz9HYAlZO5wikUexwC5y6W36wAmUxmc0WSwowO0AEZHl1tAAmexbIA and ditch the extra function.

That does make sense, there's nothing to convey they become required. Defaults is ambiguous without context but would be hard to forget once you have it. That's a neat, robust solution. You even get a sort-of TS check on each implementation, since cfg shouldn't have any optional properties. Good stuff!
